# CSS: How to decrease the margin of my paragraphs inside a div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, margin, appendchild

I'm using javascript to insert paragraphs inside a div. What it does is get the value of an input form when you click a button and append it into a specific div as a paragraph. The problem is that their margin is too big and I have no idea how to decrease them (make them closer). What do I do in this case?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ja2r6v69/3/)
- Anyway, my code looks like this:

### HTML

```
<div id="red">
    <button id="bt_1" onclick="addParagraph()">Add</button>
    <form>
        <input id="box_top" type="text" placeholder="Spacing is too big  -->">
    </form>
</div>
<div id="blue">

 <!--Paragraphs that are being added here have their top and bottom margin too big, but I don't know how to fix it.-->
 <!--Type something in thet input form and keep clicking the add button to see what I mean.-->

 </div>
```

### CSS

```
#blue {
    height:100px;
    width:250px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    background-color:blue;
    overflow:auto;
}

#red {
    height:100px;
    width:250px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    background-color:red
}

form {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Sans-Serif;
    display: inline-block;
}

#bt_1 {
    margin-left:5px;
    height:35px;
    width:70px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    border-radius:5px;
}
```

### JavaScript

```
function addParagraph() {
    var word = document.getElementById("box_top").value;

    var pMaker = document.createElement("p");
    var nodeMaker = document.createTextNode(word);
    pMaker.appendChild(nodeMaker);

    var blueDiv = document.getElementById("blue");
    blueDiv.appendChild(pMaker);
}
```

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai Thanks! I don't believe I overlooked something as basic as that and it was giving me a little headache haha. Thanks for clearing it up. :)

Comment: Ty everyone for replying, helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the following class in your css.

```
 #blue p{margin:0;}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshponnukalai/ja2r6v69/4/)

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the margin with css.

```
#blue p{
  margin:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

simply aply the css

```
#blue p {
     margin: 5px;
  }
```

or any other number instead of 5 you want to add

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add something like this to css:

```
#blue p {
  margin: 2px auto;
}
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your css: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ja2r6v69/3/)**

```
p {
    line-height: normal;
    margin: 0;
}
```